# visualize boost sml state machine

Tags: c++, boost, boost-sml

I am building a larger state machine in boost sml for the first time and need a way to visualize (e.g. export to graphviz) the whole state machine. Any idea how one could do that? Is there any way to iterate over the structure of the state machine and print it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disclaimer: I have zero experience with SML (had to find where it lives).

### First Attempt, Mmmm

However, trying some things with the `visit_current_states` interface, I came up with this ... not so nice implementation that maps out a (composite) state machine, given a list of events:

```
#include <boost/sml.hpp>

namespace sml = boost::sml;
namespace aux = sml::aux;

struct e1 {};
struct e2 {};
struct e3 {};
struct e4 {};
struct e5 {};

struct sub {
    auto operator()() const {
        using namespace sml;
        // clang-format off
        return make_transition_table(
             *"idle"_s + event<e3> = "sub1"_s
            , "sub1"_s + event<e4> = X
        );
        // clang-format on
    }
};

struct composite {
    auto operator()() const {
        using namespace sml;
        // clang-format off
        return make_transition_table(
             *"idle"_s   + event<e1> = "s1"_s
            , "s1"_s     + event<e2> = state<sub>
            , state<sub> + event<e5> = X
        );
        // clang-format on
    }
};

#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace mapper {
    namespace hana = boost::hana;
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    using boost::core::demangle;
    
    template <typename F> struct ycombine {
        ycombine(F f):f(f) {}
        F f;
        template <typename... A>
        auto operator()(A... a) const { return f(*this, a...); };
    };

    hana::tuple<e1,e2,e3,e4,e5> events;

    template <class TSM> class Vis {
      public:
        explicit Vis(const TSM& sm, std::string prefix = "") : sm_{ sm }, prefix(prefix) {}

        template <class TSub>
        void operator()(aux::string<boost::sml::sm<TSub>>) const {
            auto subname = aux::get_type_name<TSub>();

            Vis nvis(sm_, prefix + '/' + subname);
            sm_.template visit_current_states<aux::identity<TSub>>(nvis);
            prefix = nvis.prefix;
        }

        template <class TState> void operator()(TState state) const {
            prefix += "/"s + state.c_str();
        }

      private:
        const TSM& sm_;
      public:
        mutable std::string prefix;
    };

    template <typename SM>
    std::string get_current(SM const& sm) {
        Vis<SM> v{sm};
        sm.visit_current_states(v);
        return v.prefix;
    };
}

int main() {
    using namespace mapper;

    auto recurse = ycombine {
        [](auto self, auto sm) {
            hana::for_each(events, [=](auto ev) {
                auto clone = sm;
                auto from = get_current(clone);
                clone.process_event(ev);
                auto to = get_current(clone);

                if (from != to) {
                    std::cout
                        << std::quoted(from) << " -> "
                        << std::quoted(to) 
                        << " [label=" << std::quoted(demangle(typeid(ev).name())) << "]\n";

                    self(clone);
                }
            });
        } };

    std::cout << "digraph {\n";
    recurse(sml::sm<composite>{});
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

Though I have no idea how useful this is, at least I could render the result with graphviz:

[image]

### Second Attempt - READ THE FINE MANUAL :derp:

It looks like there was a cleaner way to do these things, especially the presence of the nested typedef `transitions` when reading the [latest examples](https://boost-experimental.github.io/sml/examples.html#composite):

```
// $CXX -std=c++14 plant_uml.cpp
#include <boost/sml.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace sml = boost::sml;

struct e1 {};
struct e2 {};
struct e3 {};
struct e4 {};

struct guard {
  bool operator()() const { return true; }
} guard;

struct action {
  void operator()() {}
} action;

struct plant_uml {
  auto operator()() const noexcept {
    using namespace sml;
    return make_transition_table(
       *"idle"_s + event<e1> = "s1"_s
      , "s1"_s + event<e2> [ guard ] / action = "s2"_s
      , "s2"_s + event<e3> [ guard ] = "s1"_s
      , "s2"_s + event<e4> / action = X
    );
  }
};

template <class T>
void dump_transition() noexcept {
  auto src_state = std::string{sml::aux::string<typename T::src_state>{}.c_str()};
  auto dst_state = std::string{sml::aux::string<typename T::dst_state>{}.c_str()};
  if (dst_state == "X") {
    dst_state = "[*]";
  }

  if (T::initial) {
    std::cout << "[*] --> " << src_state << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << src_state << " --> " << dst_state;

  const auto has_event = !sml::aux::is_same<typename T::event, sml::anonymous>::value;
  const auto has_guard = !sml::aux::is_same<typename T::guard, sml::front::always>::value;
  const auto has_action = !sml::aux::is_same<typename T::action, sml::front::none>::value;

  if (has_event || has_guard || has_action) {
    std::cout << " :";
  }

  if (has_event) {
    std::cout << " " << boost::sml::aux::get_type_name<typename T::event>();
  }

  if (has_guard) {
    std::cout << " [" << boost::sml::aux::get_type_name<typename T::guard::type>() << "]";
  }

  if (has_action) {
    std::cout << " / " << boost::sml::aux::get_type_name<typename T::action::type>();
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <template <class...> class T, class... Ts>
void dump_transitions(const T<Ts...>&) noexcept {
  int _[]{0, (dump_transition<Ts>(), 0)...};
  (void)_;
}

template <class SM>
void dump(const SM&) noexcept {
  std::cout << "@startuml" << std::endl << std::endl;
  dump_transitions(typename SM::transitions{});
  std::cout << std::endl << "@enduml" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  sml::sm<plant_uml> sm;
  dump(sm);
}
```

The output, for inspiration:

```
@startuml

[*] --> idle
idle --> s1 : e1
s1 --> s2 : e2 [guard] / action
s2 --> s1 : e3 [guard]
s2 --> terminate : e4 / action

@enduml
```

Obviously, not graphviz, but actually looks more "trustworthy" due to the fact that

- it resembles some kind of standard UML notation,
- was written by the library author(s?)
- included details that I wasn't able to (largely because of being unaware of their existence/working)

---

Comment: holy shit how could i have overlooked the dump example :( 
damn... thank you!

Comment: Well #metoo I guess :)

Comment: I´m impressed, you pulled that out never having looked at SML. How did you discover visit_current_states in the first place?

I´ve been looking at the page https://boost-ext.github.io/sml/index.html for 3 weeks and I just discovered it today, trying to understand what is going on in the visitor.cpp example

Comment: I think I did some keyword searches over the library source, including the examples. For what I remember I matched it in the very last sample?

Comment: The example doesn't appear to be [in the example list](https://boost-ext.github.io/sml/examples.html) though you *can* still find it [here](https://boost-ext.github.io/sml/user_guide.html). It appears that the sample has only been [added May 26th](https://github.com/boost-ext/sml/commit/da8a0cc60c53b0ea459b7cdae8d0b1e0053b4a44) and the commit message confirms that it was underdocumented. I'm pretty sure I just grepped the physical checkout and I happened to be a month *after* that sample got added :)

Comment: Jusiak's code doesn't seem to work for composite state machines, is that right? is there a version that does?